# Flex HTTPService: SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response:

Tags: apache-flex, soap, coldfusion, flex3, coldfusion-9

I am trying to connect my flex app to a CFC I have which calls a method. It's to test a login control, and when i put the correct credentials in, it comes back with the error: "SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response: ".

The CFC method is:

```
    <!--- Array of Users is called --->
    <cfset user = EntityLoad( "User", {emailAddress='#arguments.emailAddress#', password='#arguments.password#'}, true ) />
    <cfset returnvar = "false"/>    
    <cftry>
        <cfif user[1].firstName>
            <cfset returnvar = "true"/>                 
        <cfelse>
                <cfset returnvar = "true"/> 
        </cfif>                     
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset returnvar = "false"/>    
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>


            <cfreturn returnvar />
</cffunction>
```

I am not sure how to decore this. The CFC method returns back a string, which i use as a flag. Should that be changed? 
Thanks guys

Comment: Note after some testing Ive noticed, if i change the cfreturn to "test", it gets shown in the flex app, so i am deducing that something is up with the entityLoad line. Strange thing is, if i get username and password combo wrong, it shows "test" being returned but when it is right, i  am getting that same fault error

Comment: This is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581799/flex-3-and-soap-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening:

1: A user is returned ("Bob")

2: CF tries to evaluate user[1].firstname as a boolean, but Bob is not a boolean

3: The returnvar is set to false, but the error stops the function from continuing processing (this is a guess)

4: The expected value type is not returned to Flex, so Flex errors

First, I'd test step 3 by changing the catch block to

```
<cfcatch><cfreturn "false"></cfcatch>
```

Then, instead of switching on user[1].firstname, I'd switch on user.recordcount.

Comment: Thanks I worked it out using a series of cfcatch and tries, to see what we were getting back exactly :)