# Flex 3 and soap response?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flex3

I want to insert data into a SQL Server, but I keep getting this error

> RPC Fault faultString="SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response:faultCode="DecodingError" faultDetail="null"]

I can get data all day, but why can't I input any?

```
<mx:WebService id="ws" wsdl="http://localhost:/AService01.asmx?wsdl" 
 fault="onFault(event)">
<mx:operation 
name="GetEmployees" 
resultFormat="object"
result="GetEmployees(event)"/>

</mx:WebService>

<mx:Script>
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.DataGrid;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.rpc.wsdl.WSDLBinding;

private function init():void
{
    ws.GetEmployees();
}
[Bindable]
private var res:ArrayCollection;

private function GetEmployees(event:ResultEvent):void 
{
// Databind data from webservice to datagrid

res = event.result as ArrayCollection;
datagrid.dataProvider = res;

//datagrid.dataProvider = event.result[1]; 
UserText.text = event.result[1].firstname + " " + event.result[1].email;// find a better way to get this...
}

private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void {
    Alert.show(event.fault.toString());
}

private function AddRecord(event:Event):void 
{

// Save a record using a WebService method
ws.SaveEmployee(txtFirstName.text, txtLastName.text, txtEmail.text, txtPhoneNum.text, txtAddress.text, txtCity.text, txtState.text, int(txtZip.text), txtBirthday.text as Date, txtPassword.text ); 
}
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: what programming language is the webservice written in? C#? Try to call the webservice from a browser, to test if that works correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's in C# and both methods work fine in the browser.

Comment: do you run the Flex-app in your browser? Can you use FireBug to see what values are sent to the WebService? I guess you don't provide enough parameters, or the conversions (int or date) result in an invalid value

Comment: That's what was happening. I changed the int and the date everything worked!

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when you are throwing an exception in WS and trying to correctly parse in Flex. Check [this](http://blogs.triarctic.com/browndblog/?p=122) link for more info.

> Flex cannot handle faults that are associated with an HTTP 500 status.  You will get a DecodingError in this case.  This stems from Flex not being able to read the details of a fault when the response is 500.  Here is the actual Fault Flex returns.
>
> `[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response: " faultCode="DecodingError" faultDetail="null"] messageId=”52E31332-D231-3C4C-E2D1-0DDB1A1885D0″ type=”fault” bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]`